# The way to disable MS Edge's Web Notes

Tags: microsoft-edge

I'm searching for how to disable MS Edge's Web Notes functionality, which forces web pages to be reloaded. Neither settings nor advanced settings seems to provide options.
Is there other way (e.g. APIs, meta tags, registries) to do it?

Comment: If this is for you, as a user, then it's off-topic for SO. If this is for you, as a web developer, then *no*, hands off. It's a feature for users, not for you to control.

Comment: Yes it was a question as a web developer, and it should be my work to make the pages stand up to reloads. Thank you very much.